# Getting Null Pointer Exception with setCenter() method in JavaFX with Scene Builder 8.0

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, nullpointerexception, scenebuilder

I created a small program to reproduce the error I am getting in my actual project. I have a controller class called `MainWindow.java` that is responsible for two .fxml files: `MainWindow.fxml` and `AnchorTest.fxml`.
Code for the controller class:

```
package projecterror.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainWindow extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane mainWindow;

    @FXML
    Menu menuFile, menuAnalysis;
    @FXML
    MenuItem menuNew;


    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        menuNew.setOnAction((event) -> {
            try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../view/AnchorTest.fxml"));
                AnchorPane anchorTest = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
                mainWindow.setCenter(anchorTest);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Test Project");

        initMainWindow();

    }

    public void initMainWindow() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../view/MainWindow.fxml"));
            mainWindow = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(mainWindow);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            //Fullscreen
            Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
            Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();
            primaryStage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
            primaryStage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
            primaryStage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
            primaryStage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());

            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

`MainWindow.fxml` is a `BorderPane` that has a `MenuBar` on `top`. 
Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="projecterror.controller.MainWindow">
    <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu fx:id="menuFile" mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
                  <Menu fx:id="menuAnalysis" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Analysis">
                    <items>
                      <MenuItem fx:id="menuNew" mnemonicParsing="false" text="New" />
                    </items>
                  </Menu>
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

`AnchorTest.fxml` is an `AnchorPane` that has as children two `AnchorPane`.

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
            <AnchorPane layoutX="6.0" layoutY="450.0" />
            <AnchorPane layoutX="6.0" layoutY="569.0" prefHeight="116.0" prefWidth="730.0">
                  <Button layoutX="6.0"   layoutY="26.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="102.0" text="Button 1" />
                  <Button layoutX="115.0" layoutY="26.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="102.0" text="Button 2" />
                  <Button layoutX="226.0" layoutY="26.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="102.0" text="Button 3" />
                  <Button layoutX="115.0" layoutY="75.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="102.0" text="Button 4" />
                  <Button layoutX="383.0" layoutY="26.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="102.0" text="Button 5" />
                  <Button layoutX="491.0" layoutY="26.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="102.0" text="Button 6" />
                  <Button layoutX="600.0" layoutY="26.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="102.0" text="Button 7" />
                  <Button layoutX="491.0" layoutY="75.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="102.0" text="Button 8" />
                  <Button layoutX="600.0" layoutY="75.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="102.0" text="Button 9" />
                  <TextField alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="341.0" layoutY="26.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="28.0" text="10" />
            </AnchorPane>
         </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

When on `MainWindow.fxml`, after I click on the menu `File > Analysis > New`, it is supposed to place `AnchorTest.fxml` content into `MainWindow.fxml` center. However, I get the following stack trace error:

```
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at projecterror.controller.MainWindow.lambda$0(MainWindow.java:35)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The line that is flagging the NPE is:

```
mainWindow.setCenter(anchorTest);
```

I have read other questions similar to this but mostly all of their problems was regarding the path of the fxml files. I firmly believe that is not the problem since in my actual project I use the same *type* of path for other views and I don't have problem so far.
I have uploaded the project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oo0aloqihyh456f/ProjectError.zip?dl=0) in case someone wants to run the program.

Project structure is as it follows: 
[image: Project structure] 
Thanks in advance and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have never seen a `JavaFX Main` structured in this fashion.

Comment: You should also post your project's structure.

Comment: `mainWindow` is not initialized in the controller; it is initialized in the `Application` instance that is created when the application is launched (the instance on which `start()` is called). Bottom line here is you should not use the application class as the controller class; it is too confusing (and violates all sorts of basic OOP design principles, such as "Single Responsibility").

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm pretty new to software designs so it's kind of confusing for me at first. So it should work if I separate the Main from the controller classes?

Comment: Yes: create a separate controller class. You can access the border pane in it in exactly the same way you access the other elements, i.e. give the border pane a `fx:id` in the FXML file, and create a corresponding `@FXML`-annotated field in the controller.

Comment: Nominating for reopening. The Null Pointer Exception here is caused because the OP is unaware that he or she is initializing the field in a different instance than the instance in which is it being accessed. The question marked as duplicate doesn't address this scenario.

Comment: I agree with you @James_D. I have already voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you launch a JavaFX application, an instance of your application class is created, and (among other things that happen), the `start()` method is invoked on that `Application` instance on the FX Application Thread.

When you load an FXML file, if the FXML file specifies a controller class, an instance of that controller class is created, the `@FXML`-annotated fields are injected into that instance, and the `initialize()` method is called. All this happens during the call to `FXMLLoader.load()`.

Consequently, in your code, you end up with two different instances of `MainWindow`. The `start()` method is invoked on one instance, which initializes the `mainWindow` field, and the `initialize()` method is invoked on the other instance. Since `mainWindow` was never initialized in that second instance, you get a null pointer exception when you try to dereference it in the `initialize()` method.

Separate the controller class from the `Application` class. The `Application` class should do nothing other than manage the lifecycle of the application as a whole (typically, it should implement the code needed to start the application):

```
package projecterror.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainWindow extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test Project");

        initMainWindow(primaryStage);

    }

    public void initMainWindow(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../view/MainWindow.fxml"));
            BorderPane mainWindow = loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(mainWindow);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            //Fullscreen
            Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
            Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();
            primaryStage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
            primaryStage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
            primaryStage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
            primaryStage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());

            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

```
package projecterror.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class MainWindowController {

    @FXML
    private BorderPane mainWindow;

    @FXML
    Menu menuFile, menuAnalysis;
    @FXML
    MenuItem menuNew;


    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        menuNew.setOnAction((event) -> {
            try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../view/AnchorTest.fxml"));
                AnchorPane anchorTest = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
                mainWindow.setCenter(anchorTest);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }



}
```

In order for the controller to access the `BorderPane`, you need to inject it from the FXML (note the annotation on it in the controller code above). Add an `fx:id` to the element in the FXML file:

```xml
<BorderPane style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" fx:id="mainWindow"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
    fx:controller="projecterror.controller.MainWindowController">
```

Comment: Just for completeness, I think you forgot the `private Stage primaryStage;` inside MainWindow class. It works perfectly, thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @leandrocoutom Actually, I intended to omit it, since it is only needed in the `start()` and `initMainWindow()` methods, but I didn't complete the change. Let me fix....